# What makes scorpions glow under UV light?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, fluorescence

What *substance* (or class of substances) is responsible for the neon blue-colored fluorescence we observe when we shine UV light on scorpions?

[image]

Do note, I want to know *what* substance makes them glow and not *why* they glow... the latter being more suited for the Bio.SE.

Comment: See: http://www.kidsdiscover.com/quick-reads/makes-scorpions-glow-ultraviolet-light/

Comment: Interesting link here http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1074552199800854 "The fluorescence of scorpions and cataractogenesis"

Comment: Ironically, I would have said that identifying the substance is more Bio.SE and why it fluoresces is more Chem.SE.

Comment: ever-so-slightly helpful info in video: "[a nitrogenous substance in its cuticles](http://voices.nationalgeographic.com/2011/10/24/scorpions-that-glow-in-the-dark/)"  More helpful, but WIRED is not a scholarly reference: [Two compounds are involved in scorpion UV fluorescence: beta-carboline and 4-methyl, 7-hydroxycoumarin.](https://www.wired.com/2013/11/arthropods-are-having-a-secret-rave/#slide-x).

Comment: @Zhe I spent quite a bit of time deliberating over the wording I ought to use. Being a Bio. student myself, "why it fluoresces" would possibly twist the meaning of this question. For example, asking *how* fireflies glow is different from asking *why* they glow: the former occurs due to the breakdown of luciferin (this lies in the domain of Chemistry), whereas the latter is (probably) a method of locating mates at night (this is Bio. turf). Now re-read the question again ;)

Comment: Re-reading doesn't help. If you asking which specific substance makes them fluoresce, that is definitely a bio question. If you're asking about the principles of fluorescence, then it would be a chemistry question. Your wording suggests the former.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because identifying the specific substance (quite possibly a complex macromolecule) is more suited for Bio.SE.

Comment: I think that it is a chemistry  question, the chromophore is not unlike an indole /trp molecule in a protein, and properties of proteins is to me is part of chemistry. If as chemists we do not embrace new areas  our subject will fade away.

Comment: @Zhe How is asking which specific *substance* fluoresces **not** chemistry?  I strongly disagree with your idea that it isn't.

Comment: @matt_black You're not talking about spectroscopy or the process of identification. You're simply asking what it is (in terms of its biological function). This is not what chemistry is for. Otherwise, computer hardware engineering is chemistry because there are substances that make up the machine, and we care what they are. Alternatively, everything is just baryons and leptons interacting with photons. Why shouldn't the physicists answer this question?

Comment: @porphyrin We're not asking about properties. The property--fluorescence--is already known, and OP has specifically indicated that "why they glow" is not the point of this question. We're not talking about analyzing a sample for substance identification. We're asking about a specific substance in a biological context. Sure, it's a chemical but nowhere did we need to use chemical principles in a pure or applied manner.

Comment: @Zhe Biological function isn't the issue here as the questioner clearly stated. Identifying *which* molecules are responsible for something is, arguably, the *core* of chemistry. Compare: "which molecule cause the smell of rosemary" (clearly chemistry) with "why does rosemary smell" (probably biology).

Comment: @Zhe, not sure I understand your comment. How can you know what a substance is without analysis? I did indicate what these molecules might be, and I repeat, this is absolutely part of chemistry, not biology. And what is a 'biological context' at the molecular level if not chemistry? I repeat if we ignore new parts of our subject it will fade away and become irrelevant and we shall find that this science will be done by others and often not so well as we as chemists could do it.

Comment: @porphyrin matt_black I don't think I'm going to be able to convince either of you that I'm right, so I'm just going to drop it. Feel free to ping if you wish to discuss further, but I'm not sure we'll get anywhere.

Comment: **Update**: Veritasium posted a video discussing on this topic:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-Nr2z5X7Rs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72595/what-makes-scorpions-glow-under-uv-light#comment127126_72595), which links to [this paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S1074-5521(99)80085-4), and [this comment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72595/what-makes-scorpions-glow-under-uv-light#comment127162_72595), which links to [this Wired article](https://www.wired.com/2013/11/arthropods-are-having-a-secret-rave/), there are *at least* two molecules:

$\beta$-carboline:

[image]

4-methyl-7-hydroxycoumarin:

[image]

$\tiny\text{Yes I poached those comments, they could have been answers.}$

Comment: I think the brevity of this answer (which fully answers the question as stated) shows precisely why the question hardly contains any chemistry. Not that there's any biology in it, either. I think it is still chemistry, but all in all, not a very useful question. Now, if it asked about *why* these molecules fluoresce, that would be different.

Comment: @orthocresol I agree that the answer would be better if it described some of the background, like how we know these are the culprits. What do their fluorescent spectra look like, for example. Fleshed out, I think it would make a good answer.

Comment: @matt_black There is a figure from the paper I can add, and I can also give a crude comparison against some calculations. Would that be interesting?

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon Well, I think so.

Comment: @matt_black Yet, the question was not asking about how they were identified. The question only asks about what they are, and the answer to that is "they are X and Y".

Comment: @orthocresol I agree in principle with your comments, but it would be interesting to know if these molecules are just in the protein as is, or if they are chemically linked to an amino acid for example, which would be my guess. So there is much more to this yet.  It would also be interesting to know  why these compounds are there, are they photo-protectors for example, or just a byproduct of metabolism or what? Nature is generally not wasteful.